# How to create leading zeros?

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lab.Text = FormatTelephoneNumber("0034523");
}

public static string FormatTelephoneNumber(string value)
{
   value = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D").Replace(value, string.Empty);
   return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString(" #- ###-###");
```

}

Gives Output:

> 34-523

But I need output:

> 0-034-523

`0034523` would Become `0-034-523` and `00345` would become `0-034-5` (no extra valeue or `0- 000-345`)

Comment: use [PadLeft(7, '0')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add `0` characters to your string before formatting

Comment: Would you want inputs of "034523", "34523", "0034523" to give different results? If so, you should definitely *not* be converting them to integers.

Comment: return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString(" #- ###-###"); this line use 0 value not converted. so how to value return. please give example.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), you could use `0` instead of `#`

```
value.ToString("0- 000-000")
```

Comment: Maybe add some code so that the person does not need to go elsewhere.

Comment: 0034523 would Become 0-034-523 and 00345 would become 0-034-5 (no extra valeue or 0- 000-345) Please Help me any one

Comment: return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString(" #- ###-###"); this line use 0 value not converted. so how to value return. please give example

Answer (score 4):

You should not convert it to `int`. Perform the regex on the `string` itself. Converting to `int` will ignore the leading 0's.

Answer (score 3):

Use `0- 000-000` as format instead.

To get the additional requirement for the format, use two formats:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(value);

if (val < 1000)
{
    return val.ToString("0-000-0");
}
else
{
    return val.ToString("0-000-000");
}
```

The `0` is used to indicate padding.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.